# Binding handler to onLoad event inside directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am setting directive on a `div` element, and want to bind that element's `load` event to an event handler, something like this:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', function ) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        compile: function(tElement, tAttributes) {
           return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.bind('load', function (event) {
                        console.log('Loaded');
                    }
                post: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

                }
        }
}
```

However, load handler is never executed, as if the div element is loaded before the element is bound. Is there a way to bind element before it is loaded ?

Comment: What kind of element is it?

Comment: And yes, you can, look at the compile function of directives

Comment: Sorry, don't know how I missed it. I'm trying to apply directive on a div element, something like this <div my-directive></div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use an angular event listener in a custom directive attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433265/can-you-use-an-angular-event-listener-in-a-custom-directive-attribute)