# Can you use an angular event listener in a custom directive attribute?

Tags: angularjs, events

In normal HTML we can directly add listeners to events on HTML elements e.g.

```
<button onclick="doMyMethod()">Click me</button>
```

I have a custom directive which emits an event, "dataLoaded". I'd like to declaratively add a handler to the element to deal with that event. However I'm not sure how to do this

I'm making up a methodology here but I'd like to do something like:

```
<my-element ng-on="'dataLoaded', doMyMethod" ></my-element>
```

### The (undesirable) alternative

The alternative is to use `$scope.$on("dataLoaded", doMyMethod())` in the controller but I would prefer to declare this on the element itself.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just curious, why do you throw the event in the first place instead of invoking some code in an "angular way"?

Comment: Of course, it's very simple. Post your directive code.

Comment: this syntax would be better `on-event="{dataLoaded: doMyMethod}"`

Comment: How about something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/DfGM2w0z78sJsfb9Bdkd?p=preview. A custom directive which converts declarative way to listen to broadcast.

Comment: @Bharat that's a pretty nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an event here, you should pass your method into the directive like so:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myElement', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
           // way to bind method to your directive's scope
           dataLoaded: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            ...
            // instead of triggering data loaded, call method bound to scope
            scope.dataLoaded();
            ...
        }
});
```

Your HTML:

```
<my-element data-loaded="doMyMethod"></my-element>
```

Comment: Without context, this is the correct solution (design-wise). However, OP specifically asked to listen for an event and I guess he has his reasons to do that(events are very different from explicit callback bindings). So actually you are not answering his questions

Comment: @LionC I think this is exactly what OP wants.

Comment: Haven't implemented it yet. I do think this is where I'm trying to get to. However as @lionC said, I would ideally like to use the syntax in the question. That said this is a fine answer

Comment: If you want to listen to the event, simply put the event listener inside the directive ( scope.$on('dataLoaded') ) and call the method there. The concept is the same though, you will want to pass your method into the directive because angular doesn't have a declarative way to listen to custom events afaik.